# Are there any distributed filesystems in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

Are there any distributed filesystems in OpenBSD?

But not firstly from the ports, rather in the base!

Maybe found AFS, but there is only client? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems

Comment: You probably don’t want OpenAFS unless you plan on running several servers and a Kerberos infrastructure. It doesn’t simply export a volume like with NFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. Filesystems are the weakest point of OpenBSD.

There is a port of OpenAFS, though.

https://home.apache.org/~dch/blog/2007/11/24/running-openafs-on-openbsd/ (running OpenAFS on OpenBSD · Random Musings)

Comment: The most common response when someone asks on the mailing lists about "new filesystems in OpenBSD" is "no" and "where is your patch?"  :-)